# Setting up GitLab 8.16.0 on a vServer running Ubuntu 14.04 with Plesk and Apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab, plesk, vhosts

I was trying to install GitLab on my vServer and found out that it could be quite a hard task if you do not have knowledge in server administration/configuration at all.

**Task**: Install **GitLab** 8.16.0 CE on a **virtual host**. Server is running on **Ubuntu 14.04,** domain management via **Plesk** and the webserver should be **apache2**.

Even several people out there had similar problems like me, it was necessary to collect the final solution from several sources.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps seem to work:

#### 1. Add your (sub-)domain in Plesk.

In this example I chose the subdomain `git.myVServer.com`.

#### 2. Edit apache config

- Go to the config directory

  ```
  cd /etc/apache2/
  ```
- Add `Listen 81` to the `ports.conf` file
- Go to the additional config file of your vhost

  ```
  cd /var/www/vhosts/system/git.myVServer.com/conf/
  ```
- Add a vhost.conf with following content
  (Adapted from this [GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf))

  ```apache
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public  
  ServerName http://git.myVServer.com  
  ServerSignature Off  
  ProxyPreserveHost On  
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode  
  <Location \>
      Require all granted
      #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse  
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8081  
      ProxyPassReverse http://git.myVServer.com:81  
  </Location>  
  RewriteEngine on  

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents  
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*  
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]  

  # needed for downloading attachments  
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public  

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.  
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html  
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html  
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html  
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html  
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html  

  # It is assumed that the log directory is in /var/log/httpd.  
  # For Debian distributions you might want to change this to  
  # /var/log/apache2.  
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded  
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_error.log  
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_forwarded.log common_forwarded  
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_access.log combined env=!dontlog  
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.log combined
  ```
- Apply the changes of your vhost

  ```
  /opt/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain git.myVServer.com
  ```
- Restart apache

  ```
  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
  ```

#### 3. Install GitLab

- Follow the GitLab-ce omnibus install instructions on [this page](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404).

  1. `sudo apt-get install curl openssh-server ca-certificates postfix`
  2. `curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`
  3. `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce`
- Before running the GitLab reconfiguration, we have to change some settings:
  `cd /etc/gitlab/`
  and make sure the following settings are not commented out and set to:

  ```ruby
  external_url 'http://git.myVServer.com'
  gitlab_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8081'  
  gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"  
  gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"  
  unicorn['port'] = 8081  

  nginx['enable'] = false  
  web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
  ```
- Apply changes:

  ```
  gitlab-ctl reconfigure
  ```
- Check if everything is fine:

  ```
  gitlab-ctl status
  ```

#### 4. Done.

Now, if everything went to plan, your GitLab instance should be running and you can reach it from
`http://git.myVServer.com`

---

**Afterword**:
As I have no well-funded knowledge of configuring things like these, I would be happy if I get corrected wherever possible.

Comment: Well.. I was not able to style the code blocks correctly. How do I escape HTML-looking parts like `<Location />` ?